# Merge two DataFrames on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

hope you can help me.

I have two pretty big Datasets.
DF1 Example:

```
|id| A_Workflow_Type_ID | B_Workflow_Type_ID | ...
 1   123                  456
 2   789                  222                  ...
 3   333                  NULL                 ...
```

DF2 Example:

```
Workflow| Operation | Profile |    Type     | Name | ...
123           1          2       Low_Cost     xyz    ...
456           2          5       High_Cost    z      ...
```

I need to merge the two datasets without creating many NaNs and multiple columns. So i merge on the informations A_Workflow_Type_ID and B_Workflow_Type_ID from DF1 on Workflow from DF2. 
I tried it with several join operations in pandas and the merge option it failure.

My last try:

```
all_Data = pd.merge(left=DF1,right=DF2, how='inner', left_on =['A_Workflow_Type_ID ','B_Workflow_Type_ID '], right_on=['Workflow'])
```

But that returns an error that they have to be equal lenght on both sides.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need reshape first by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
#generate all column without strings Workflow
cols = DF1.columns[~DF1.columns.str.contains('Workflow')]
print (cols)
Index(['id'], dtype='object')

df = DF1.melt(cols, value_name='Workflow', var_name='type')
print (df)
   id                type  Workflow
0   1  A_Workflow_Type_ID     123.0
1   2  A_Workflow_Type_ID     789.0
2   3  A_Workflow_Type_ID     333.0
3   1  B_Workflow_Type_ID     456.0
4   2  B_Workflow_Type_ID     222.0
5   3  B_Workflow_Type_ID       NaN

all_Data = pd.merge(left=df,right=DF2,  on ='Workflow')
print (all_Data)
   id                type Workflow  Operation  Profile       Type Name
0   1  A_Workflow_Type_ID      123          1        2   Low_Cost  xyz
1   1  B_Workflow_Type_ID      456          2        5  High_Cost    z
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much Sir! The melt function is exactly what i needed.